# Django manytomany m2m_changed script works, but how?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have a model:

```
class Course(models.Model):
class Meta:
    ordering = ['completion_order']
    degree                = models.ForeignKey(Degree, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name                  = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    completion_order      = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0,null=False, blank=False)
    required              = models.ManyToManyField('Task', default=1, blank=True, symmetrical=False)
```

And I have written a function to run on "m2m_changed" to automatically adjust the completion order to take into account any changes in prerequisites:

```
def required_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    degreecourses = Courses.objects.all().filter(degree=instance.degree)
    for zcr in degreecourses: #resets the order for the all the degree's course instances
        zcr.completion_order = 0
    for cr in degreecourses: #assigns new completion_order values
        if cr.required.count() is 0: # if no requirements sets 'completion_order' to 1 
            cr.completion_order = 1
        else: #sets 'completion_order' to the increment of the highest (max) value of this courses's required course
            mx = cr.required.all().aggregate(Max('completion_order'))
            neworder = mx['completion_order__max'] + 1
            cr.completion_order = neworder
        cr.save()
```

This is run after any change in the m2m thus:

```
m2m_changed.connect(required_changed, sender=Course.required.through)
```

I originally set this up iterating through multiple times, but then realised it was unnecessary -my (novice) question is:

**Can someone explain how this is able to resolve all of the "required" values in one pass, i.e. without having to iterate through the second loop multiple times?**

I'm guessing it's to do with python being object oriented - but I'm new to object oriented programming, so whilst I'm pleased it works, I'm perplexed as to how it can assign the correct running order (i.e. even with many complex interdependencies between multiple courses) with *seemingly* only one pass?

Comment: Not sure it's what you're asking, but I think when you set a handler to get a signal every time a `m2m` is updated, you'll receive *all* the current attributes id in the `pk_set`, not only the ones that got updated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, I think I understood that, but logically, in order for the values to be set, the loop would have to iterate through the query set multiple times. The loop only increments by one, so after only one pass I was expecting the highest order number to be 2 (i.e. 1+1!), so my question is about the mechanics of the script -  how are they all resolved up to their final values in a single pass? Are they evaluated in parallel or something?